# AngularJS Passing a list into $http.get()

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, servlets, get

I have a route on my server that is designed to handle a list of objects passed through a GET request. It does this by flattening fields of the same name.

For example:

> GET http://example.com/services/echo?list=Hello&list=Stay&list=Goodbye

would be deserialized to a list containing `['Hello', 'Stay', 'Goodbye']`

How would I replicate this behavior when using Angular's `$http` service?  One way is to build the URI string manually.  Another is to configure the servlet to deserialize the list from one field.  But is there a cleaner way to do this, e.g. by using the `config` object?

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl',params:{list:['foo','bar']}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // this callback will be called asynchronously
  // when the response is available
}).
```